# Rails 4: helper f.date has different dd/mm/yyyy order for firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am using the rails `f.date` helper in a `form_for`. I am being a little confused by  the following phenomena. When I am using Chrome, I type in the date

```
'06/15/2015'
```

for my `anticipated_arrival_date` field.

Which, in my Model, successfully evaluates the following comparison:

```
(record.start_date <= record.anticipated_arrival_date) or ((record.start_date - record.anticipated_arrival_date).to_i >= 7)
```

However, when I am in Firefox, and I type the same date in:

`06/15/2015`

I get the following error:

```
comparison of Date with nil failed
```

Where the my params are set as the following:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cstCV38Ap9Ig1n8L9E9SE5xjDc886uuym5x6cvfVjqk=",
 "school_application"=>{"family_name"=>"xf",
 "first_name"=>"dfg",
 "address"=>"dfg",
 "address_2"=>"gsdf1efg",
"city_state_province"=>"`sdf",
 "state_province"=>"sfd",
 "postal_code"=>"sdf",
 "country"=>"sfd",
 "phone_number"=>"sfd",
 "fax_number"=>"sdf",
 "email"=>"dfijdf@gmail.com",
 "gender"=>"fds",
 "date_of_birth"=>"10/3/2014",
 "country_of_citizenship"=>"sdf",
 "country_of_birth"=>"sfd",
 "transfer_student"=>"false",
 "I_20"=>"false",
 "fls_center"=>"8",
 "program"=>"31",
 "duration"=>"1",
 "start_date"=>" June 21,
 2015",
 "housing_type"=>"15",
 "anticipated_arrival_date"=>"06/18/2015",
 "health_insurance"=>"false",
 "express_delivery"=>"false",
 "sevic"=>"false",
 "arrival_airport"=>"2",
 "airport_pick_up"=>"0",
 "airport_drop_off"=>"0",
 "unaccompanied_minor_option"=>"false",
 "work_with_ad"=>"false",
 "agency"=>"sdf",
 "comments"=>"sdf",
 "pay_application_fee_or_full"=>"true",
 "read_everything"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Continue To Payment"}
```

Which I believe happens as it is interpreting "06/18/2015" as DD/MM/YYYY
and therefore gets `nil` as there is no 18th month of a calendar year.

How can I standardized how my `f.date` input is interpreted independent of Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the w3schools:

*Note:  elements with type="date" are not supported in Internet Explorer or Firefox.*

Which would explain a lot.

If I make it a simple `f.text-field` then tell the user how to enter the Date, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[date_field](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-date_field)** it returns a `#text_field` of type `date`. It support from Rails 4

Example from docs:

```
date_field("user", "born_on")
# => <input id="user_born_on" name="user[born_on]" type="date" />
```